# python install folder and delivering path to a local variable

Tags: python, jython

I have two questions:

I am running a python script on my computer but I have not installed python on my computer.
Could it be that first of all the script connects to a server and then runs the commands?

The second one:
Is there any option to deliver to a variable in python a path to a local variable?
And is this the option:
`Rcc=%java_home%`

I am breaking my head on this.
Thanks everyone who try to help.

Comment: If you don't have Python on your computer, how would the script (which is written in Python) connect to another computer to run the commands?

Comment: You have Python installed on your computer if the script is running and you're sure it's a python script. What operating system are you using?